# Ant Design Form validation required field

Tags: reactjs, antd

Currently, I am using Ant Design v4, Form to validate the input.

When I set the input as required:true, it renders * in front of the label (title).

My form has 7-8 items, and all of them are required. therefore I want to remove this * from the UI.

How can I do that please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The * is added via CSS. There's no way to stop ant from adding a `.ant-form-item-required` class but you could override the CSS

This should do it:

```css
.ant-form-item-label>label.ant-form-item-required::before{
   content: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set `requiredMark` prop to `false` on the Form component to hide required markers (*).

Answer (score 0):

```
<Form requiredMark={false}>
  {children}
<Form/>
```

This will hide the required mark at the form level.